# Webdriver not capturing error message on website using Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

I am a newbie trying to learn Eclipse and have come across a problem which i cannot
find an answer for. I am trying to use Datadriven framework to capture an error message
on a website, and have that displayed on the console, but webdriver is not displaying 
the message. I tried using both IE 11 and Firefox and have same issue. Here is the code 
I am using:

```
for (int k=1;k<myRows;k++){
    MyFirstName=myXLSheet[k][0];
    MyLastName=myXLSheet [k][1];
    MyEmailID=myXLSheet [k][2];
    MyReenterEmail=myXLSheet [k][2];
    MyPassword=myXLSheet [k][3];
    MyMonth=myXLSheet [k][4];
    MyDay=myXLSheet [k][5];
    MyYear=myXLSheet [k][6];

    mydriver.navigate().to(myURL);  

    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_1']")).sendKeys(MyFirstName);

    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_3']")).sendKeys(MyLastName);

    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_5']")).sendKeys(MyEmailID);

    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_8']")).sendKeys(MyReenterEmail);

    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_a']")).sendKeys(MyPassword);

    //Select Month from Dropdown
    Select month=new Select (mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='month']")));
        month.selectByVisibleText(MyMonth);

    //Select Day Dropdown
    Select day=new Select (mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']")));
        day.selectByVisibleText(MyDay);

    //Select Year Dropdown
    Select year=new Select (mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='year']")));
        year.selectByVisibleText(MyYear);

    //Choose Male/Female radio button
    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='u_0_e']")).click();    

    //Click on Signup
    mydriver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@id='u_0_i']")).click(); 

    search_result=mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reg_error_inner']")).getText();

      System.out.println(search_result);

    if (search_result.equals("Please choose a more secure password. It should be longer than 6          characters, unique to you, and difficult for others to guess.")){
        System.out.println("Pass: error message exists on using unsecured and 6 characters long password");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fail: error message does not exist on using unsecured password");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code block looks seriously jacked up and use of `{}` does not make sense to me. Edited see if that's what it was supposed to be

Comment: Is there a error Message, or so? Does something work? how is the general Setup?

Comment: I get the else message: Fail: error message does not exist on using unsecured password even though the first message is displayed on the website.

Comment: @Saifur  Tried the edited code and now it does not even click the signup button to display the error message.

Comment: It's not posted. Still in queue

Comment: Approved and just Posted!

Comment: @Saifur Tried the edited code and now it does not even click the signup button to display the error message. Everything was working up to point where it was not picking up the correct error message. Not sure if a wait statement would work, but don't know how to insert that or where. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Is it working up to the point of clicking? if so, you can use `implicit` wait. Something like `//Click on Signup
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("div[@id='u_0_i']")));
 myDynamicElement.click(); `

Comment: See [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) how to use implicit and explicit wait work

Comment: Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Saifur Did not work, i gave up. Don't want to drag this thread. Thanks for your help.